# In React Native using ImagePicker to Upload image from gallery.. need base64 string image

Tags: reactjs, image, base64, native

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
    console.log('Response = ', response);

    if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
    }
    else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    }
    else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    }
    else {
        //let source = { uri: response.uri };
        // You can also display the image using data:
        let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
        this.setState({
            ImageSource: source,
            data: response.data,
        });

    }
});

bodyFormData.append('image', {
    uri: this.state.ImageSource, // your file path string
    name: 'image1.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpg'
});

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://',
    data: bodyFormData,
    config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }
})
```

Comment: Hi, Is there a question here? what is the issue you have? I will say I hope this is a bad case of copy paste... considering the way it is  now it looks like you are trying to access state somewhere outside of a react class?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
  } else {
    const source = { uri: response.uri };

    this.setState({
      ImageSource:source,
    });
  }
});
```

in render

```
          <Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={this.state.ImageSource} />

        </View>
```

Comment: Don't add code in comments - you can [edit] your answer. Add also short explanation how/why this code solves issue